# Не могу запустить mysql сервер

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Не могу запустить mysql командой

```
mysql -u root -p
```

После ввода пароля выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

при запуске

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

```
sudo service mysql start:
```

Error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

Error:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-09-25 17:43:51 EEST; 1min 21s ago
    Process: 7786 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is>
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

```
journalctl -xe
```

Error:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-09-25 17:43:51 EEST; 2min 24s ago
    Process: 7786 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is>
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 25 17:43:51 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

(remind) hulimulushka@hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~/coding/python/remind$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
(remind) hulimulushka@hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6:~/coding/python/remind$ journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Произошел сбой юнита mysql.service.
-- 
-- Результат: failed.
сен 25 17:46:24 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is>
-- Subject: Назначен автоматический перезапуск юнита
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Назначен автоматический перезапуск юнита mysql.service, так как для него был задан 
-- параметр Restart=.
сен 25 17:46:24 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита mysql.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Процесс остановки юнита mysql.service был завершен.
сен 25 17:46:24 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
сен 25 17:46:24 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
сен 25 17:46:24 hulimulushka-HP-ProBook-450-G6 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита mysql.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Произошел сбой юнита mysql.service.
-- 
-- Результат: failed.
```

Comment: Во-первых, обе эти команды не запускают сервер, а подключаются к заранее запущенному серверу. Во-вторых, как вы ставили mysql и какую версию?

Comment: https://tproger.ru/articles/django-sqlite-to-mysql/
По этому туториалу

Comment: sudo service mysql start

Comment: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`

Comment: Ну собственно сделайте что предлагает этот текст

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение об ошибке содержит строку:

> ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

В man 5 systemd.exec для кода возврата 203 даётся следующее описание:

> The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file.

То есть, проверьте, на месте ли у вас исполняемый файл сервера MySQL, также стоит проверить наличие bash, который используется для запуска упомянутого файла /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start, например так:

ls -l /usr/sbin/mysqld /bin/bash

Результат может быть примерно таким (для Ubuntu 18.04):

```
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1113504 июн  7  2019 /bin/bash
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24691368 июл 20 13:50 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Проверьте, что оба файла существуют и для них установлены права на чтение и запуск.